# Will Java garbage collection a class if its state is used elsewhere

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

Suppose I create a `List<Double>` that will eventually by GCd. However this time I house it in a class `Foo` alongside an instance of `Bar`. `Bar` is specified in the constructor of `Foo` and the instance will be used later in the program (i.e. it won't be GCd).

```
public class Foo {
    Bar bar;
    List<Double> someList;

    public Foo(Bar bar, List<Double> someList) {
        this.bar=bar;
        this.someList=someList;
    }
}
```

Note that the `Foo` instance will never be used again -- only the `Bar` instance is used. Will `Foo` and `someList` be GCd?

Comment: If bar is inside a method of foo, and will be used, doesnt that mean that you have to call foo.someMethod();? In that case foo will be used.

Comment: Any object that can't be reached from a GC root will be collected, so in your case both the instance of `Foo` and `List` it references can be collected

Comment: @Pphoenix No, `bar` also is in other objects too and is used there (instead of in any `Foo` instance).

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is very confused. You're not asking about class GC at all. You're asking about collection of containing instances. A containing instance isn't collected until there are no references to it, and, while there are, it maintains its own references to whatever it contains, so they can't be GC-d either. You have it back to front.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that the `Bar` instance that `bar` refers to is reachable from somewhere else ... and it is therefore not eligible for garbage collection.

You then seem to ask if this has any influence on whether / when the `Foo` instance and the `List<Double>` instance are garbage collected.

- The `Foo` instance will eligible for garbage collection when it is no longer reachable.
- The `List<Double>` instance is eligible for garbage collection when it is no longer reachable.
- Assuming that there is no path from the `Bar` instance to the other two instances, the fact that the `Bar` is reachable doesn't make the other two objects reachable.

So the answer is No.  It has no influence.

Reachability is determined by following the pointers / references forwards ... not backwards.